# Why is Array Merge Not Working in a For Loop

Tags: php, arrays

In the for loop I am merging the arrays but only the last one is added at the end of the loop.

```
$result = json_decode($response['body']);

if(isset($result->{'items'})) {
    $count = count($result->{'items'});
} else {
   $count = 0;
}
$json = [];
if($count > 0) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if (isset($result->{'items'}[$i]->{'title'})) {
            $title = $result->{'items'}[$i]->{'title'};
            $title_array = array('title' => $title);
            $json = array_merge($json, $title_array);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the last title array in the loop is showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are attempting to merge an array which contains `'title' => 'x'` with another which contains `'title' => 'y'`. Since they both contain the same keys, the second overwrites the first. You need to change this line:

```
$json = array_merge($json, $title_array);
```

to

```
$json[] = $title_array;
```

Then you will get an array of arrays with titles e.g.

```
[['title' => 'x'], ['title' => 'y']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$json = array_merge($json, $title_array);
```

By the following:

```
array_push($json, $title_array); // it will push the the new array to `$json`
```